# How to deal with a private repository

Tags: git, github

I need to create a private repository in GitHub so me and my colleagues can write/modify a project in the same time.

I literally spent hours on Google and StackOverflow looking for a clear/simple way to do that but I still can't find anything like that.

Do you have any suggestions please ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: do do *what*, use git?  I assume you did manage to create a private repository since that's dead simple.

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes of course but I still don't know how each of us (me and my colleagues) can write/modify the project (e.g adding lines in the code, adding new files/folders,..) in the same time.

Comment: "but I still don't know how each of us (me and my colleagues) can write/modify the project (e.g adding lines in the code, adding new files/folders,..) in the same time" The way to do that is to use Git. That is exactly what Git lets you do.

Comment: Thanks @matt. Can you share with me any useful article (here in SO or in the internet) that speaks about the Git commands that the collaborators should use/run in their local machines ?

Comment: They all simply need to learn Git.

Comment: [This article takes an academic though pragmatic approach to explaining git and goes through some good workflow examples](
https://frontend.turing.edu/lessons/module-1/git-and-github.html?ads_cmpid=6451354298&ads_adid=76255849919&ads_matchtype=&ads_network=g&ads_creative=517671727591&utm_term=&ads_targetid=dsa-19959388920&utm_campaign=&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&ttv=2&gclid=CjwKCAjw4JWZBhApEiwAtJUN0J-8wnN57gSAYuK2Ev2N2Av2RvHa2Ja5V-eTJ517_RWQnQHLZGvXFRoCbucQAvD_BwE)

Comment: As far as what the git workflow should look, I highly recommend a simple continuously integrated workflow such as https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/github-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have code on your local machine that you'd like to publish on GitHub, do this:

- In the local folder, start a new git folder by running

  ```
  git init
  ```
- Go https://github.com/?tab=repositories and click "New" to create a new repo. Don't forget to make it "Private".
- After you do that, GitHub will tell you how to push local code to your repo. In short, you go to your local folder and do this:

  ```
  git remote add origin git@github.com:<yourusername>/<projectname>.git
  git branch -M main
  git push -u origin main
  ```

Then you should be able to go to your GitHub repository pages and check the code posted.

With the repo up and ready, your collaborators can start adding "Pull Requests" in order to allow modifications. For this, it's good practice to create a branch separate from `main`, say `develop`, where features can be added. How to do that is probably topic for another question.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. My local folder project has a folder called `venv` (python requirements/libraries) with a size of 800mb, will this folder be pushed as well to the private repository ?If no, how the collaborators will be able to run the code in their machines ?

Comment: By default, everything on your local repo will be pushed, including `venv`. My guess is that this folder correspond to virtual environment stuff, right? My suggestion is to verify whether this is something that you decided to use (maybe accidentally, or maybe because of specific versioning  of dependencies or whatnot), or if it's something someone else asked you to have in your code.  If it's the former, you should revisit how your code is organized in terms of dependencies before pushing.

Comment: That's clear. Now if a collaborator edited a part of the code and then pushed his commit to the repo, how can I accept or refuse his edit ? Sorry if my question are stupid but I'm really stuck.

Comment: No worries! Your collaborators can clone your repo and made any changes they want, but these changes will only affect their local clones. If your collabs want to push these changes to your repo, they'll have to "Fork" your repo and open a "Pull Request". The instructions they should follow are here: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my questions. I'll try to understand the documentation. Feel free to share with me any useful articles that can help me and my colleagues handle the project versions.

Comment: No problem! I'd recommend you to skip the actual dox and check this little tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-first-pull-request-on-github-3/   Also, you should mark this question as solved, and open new questions if you find yourself having a difficult with new subjects outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a repository on GitHub there's a radio button that allows you to choose if it's public or private. Setting it to private should do the trick:

[image]